# Can I read IMEI without permission in android internal source

Tags: android

I need to read `IMEI` value in opencore source code(c file).

I will use `IMEI` for `drm` file encoding.

Some multimedia has not permission for `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

So I need to read `IMEI` value without permission.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If there was a way to do something, that requires permission, without granting that permission to application, then there would be no sense to use permission system in the first place.

Having said that, there theoretically might be some hacks, but they will be treated as security flaw and will be fixed in further releases. I would strongly recommend against using them (assuming you find one).

Its much easier to specify what security permissions your DRM library depends on then rely on some hacks.